# Intuition behind Edge Detection Matrices in Convolution Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and attempting to understand how CNN performs image classification

i have gone through multiple youtube videos, multiple blogs and papers as well. And they all mention roughly the same thing:

1. add filters to get feature maps
2. perform pooling
3. remove linearity using RELU
4. send to a fully connected network.

While this is all fine and dandy, i dont really understand how convolution works in essence. Like for example. edge detection.

like for ex: [[-1, 1], [-1,1]] detects a vertical edge.

How? Why? how do we know for sure that this will detect a vertical edge .

Similarly matrices for blurring/sharpening, how do we actually know that they will perform what they are aimed for.

do i simply takes peoples word for it?

Please help/ i feel helpless since i am not able to understand convolution and how the matrices detects edges or shapes

Comment: hi can someone please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters detect spatial patterns such as edges in an image by detecting the changes in intensity values of the image.

**A quick recap:** In terms of an image, a high-frequency image is the one where the intensity of the pixels changes by a large amount, while a low-frequency image the one where the intensity is almost uniform. An image has both high and low frequency components. The high-frequency components correspond to the edges of an object because at the edges the rate of change of intensity of pixel values is high.

**High pass filters** are used to enhance the high-frequency parts of an image.

Let's take an **example** that a part of your image has pixel values as [[10, 10, 0], [10, 10, 0], [10, 10, 0]] indicating the image pixel values are decreasing toward the right i.e. the image changes from light at the left to dark at the right. The filter used here is [[1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1]].

Now, we take the convolutional of these two matrices that give the output [[10, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0]]. Finally, these values are summed up to give a pixel value of 30, which gives *the variation in pixel values as we move from left to right*. Similarly, we find the subsequent pixel values.

[image: vertical edge detection]

Here, you will notice that a rate of change of pixel values varies a lot from left to right thus a **vertical edge** has been detected. Had you used the filter [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, -1]], you would get the convolutional output consisting of 0s only i.e. no horizontal edge present. In the similar ways, [[-1, 1], [-1, 1]] detects a vertical edge.

You can check more here in a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuD4C8vJzEQ) by Andrew Ng.

**Edit:** Usually, a vertical edge detection filter has bright pixels on the left and dark pixels on the right (or vice-versa). The sum of values of the filter should be 0 else the resultant image will become brighter or darker. Also, in convolutional neural networks, the filters are *learned* the same way as hyperparameters through backpropagation during the training process.

Comment: thank you for your response.  one question though, and this is where i land into trouble. [-1,2,-1],[-1,2,-1],[-1,2,-1] is also a vertical detector. how come? going by the same logic can we have this [-1,200,-9],[-1,200,-9],[-1,200,-9] also as a vertical edge detector?

Comment: One important thing I forgot to mention is that the sum of values in filter should be 0. I have updated the answer! The second example can act as vertical edge detector if you replace -9 with 9 or -1 with 1, but it won't that good because sum isn't 0. The first example you showed is a line detection filter. I tried it on an image, it showed bad results as edge detection. A good example of edge detection filter is sobel's filter. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359485/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-and-an-edge-in-image-detection