# How to get rid of double edges using Canny edge detector?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

Canny edge detector from skimage, also as my own version, leaves double edges. How to implement this detector, leaving only inner or outer edges? Here are some samples of edges map.[image: Temporary]

[image]

Comment: You are attempting to detect a line using an edge detector. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359884/7328782) for the difference between edges and lines, and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414532/7328782) for the effect of a basic edge or line detector applied to a line.

Comment: @ YvesDaoust The thing is I want edges to be 1 pixel wide. I'm trying to implement General Hough Transform, where I need a temporary, which should be 1 pixel wide.

Comment: Use morphological thinning, or the inside contour or the outside contour. Anything but not Canny !