# Unable to get accurate contour of Images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm attempting to accurately get the contour of the bounding box around the comic book cover in the attached example images.

[image][image]

This is the code that I currently have.

```
from pyimagesearch import imutils
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", required = True,
    help = "Path to the query image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


print(args["query"])
# load the query image, compute the ratio of the old height
# to the new height, clone it, and resize it
image = cv2.imread(args["query"])
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 300)
# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
# in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)


#find contours in the edged image, keep only the largest
# ones, and initialize our screen contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:4]
screenCnt = None

# loop over our contours

rect_cnts = []
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4: # shape filtering condition
        screenCnt = approx
        break

print(screenCnt)
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3) 
cv2.imshow("Book Image", image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The problem arises when I try to do the shape filtering.

```
rect_cnts = []
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4: # shape filtering condition
        screenCnt = approx
        break
```

It appears as if the contours returned are not qualifying as a rectangle. I'm not sure how to fine-tune this so that the contour is better. These are the results I'm currently getting.

[image][image]

Comment: I suppose you are trying to locate the comic book in the image. Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644977/recognizing-corners-page-with-opencv-partialy-fails/

Comment: After finding edges try morphological operations to close disconnected edges. Then proceed to find contours