# Find remaining line from rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm detecting a rectangle with known dimensions in OpenCV. I've written code - which works - for detecting all four lines, but the furthest line is difficult to detect and usually causes problems when it comes time for warp the perspective.

My question (which I've looked into, but haven't found an answer for), is whether, theoretically, having 3 lines (angles and intercept) is enough to approximate the final line.[image]

EDIT: I was asked to include my current code. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

# find intersection of lines
def line_intersect(m1, b1, m2, b2):

    if m1 == m2:
        print ("These lines are parallel!!!")
        return None

    x = int((b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2))

    y = int(m1 * x + b1)

    return [x,y]

# method specs
width_error = 10
height_error = 10
kernel_size = 7
kernel_dilate = np.ones((1, 1), 'uint8')
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), 'uint8')

# read and process image
img = cv2.imread('assets/game-frames/hard-m-2019-124-1200.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, 0, 100, apertureSize = 3)
dilate_img = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel_dilate, iterations=3)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# find hough lines
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(closing, 2, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength=20, maxLineGap=10)
lines_np = np.reshape(lines, (np.int32(lines.size/4), 4))
lines_np = lines_np[(lines_np[:, 2] - lines_np[:, 0]) != 0]
lines_np = np.c_[lines_np, (lines_np[:, 3] - lines_np[:, 1])/(lines_np[:, 2] - lines_np[:, 0])]
lines_np = np.c_[lines_np, np.sqrt((lines_np[:, 3] - lines_np[:, 1])**2 + (lines_np[:, 2] - lines_np[:, 0])**2)]

# find lengthwise lines
lengthwise_lines = lines_np[(abs(lines_np[:, 4]) < 3.5) & (abs(lines_np[:, 4]) > 1.20) & (lines_np[:, 5] > 100)]
if lengthwise_lines[:, 4].size < 2: print('No lengthwise lines!')
ward_length = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = None, distance_threshold = 0.50, linkage = "ward").fit(abs(lengthwise_lines[:, 4].reshape(-1,1)))
lengthwise_lines = np.c_[lengthwise_lines, ward_length.labels_]
length_clusts = np.bincount(ward_length.labels_).argsort()[-2:]
lengthwise_lines = lengthwise_lines[np.isin(ward_length.labels_, length_clusts)]

# find extremities
x_max = np.max(lengthwise_lines[:,[0,2]].reshape(-1,1))
x_min = np.amin(lengthwise_lines[:,[0,2]])
y_coords = lengthwise_lines[:, [1, 3]].reshape(-1,1)
ward = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = None, distance_threshold = 10, linkage = "ward").fit(y_coords)
want_clusts = np.bincount(ward.labels_).argsort()[-2:]
y_ext1 = np.median(y_coords[np.isin(ward.labels_, want_clusts[0])])
y_ext2 = np.median(y_coords[np.isin(ward.labels_, want_clusts[1])])
y_max = max(y_ext1, y_ext2)
y_min = min(y_ext1, y_ext2)

# find outer lengthwise lines
length_want = ward_length.labels_[np.isin(ward_length.labels_, length_clusts)][np.argmin(abs(lengthwise_lines[:,4]))]
lengthwise_lines = lengthwise_lines[lengthwise_lines[:, 6] == length_want]
lengthwise_lines = np.c_[lengthwise_lines, (lengthwise_lines[:,1] - (lengthwise_lines[:,4]*lengthwise_lines[:,0]))]
lengthwise_lines = np.c_[lengthwise_lines, ((np.max(lengthwise_lines[:,1]) - lengthwise_lines[:,5])/lengthwise_lines[:,4])]

# subset left and right outer lengthwise lines
l_left = lengthwise_lines[lengthwise_lines[:,4] < 0]
l_right = lengthwise_lines[lengthwise_lines[:,4] > 0]

# find top and bottom lines
widthwise_lines = lines_np[(abs(lines_np[:, 4]) < 0.10)]
widthwise_lines = np.c_[widthwise_lines, (widthwise_lines[:,1] - (widthwise_lines[:,4]*widthwise_lines[:,0]))]
bottom_lines = widthwise_lines[np.where((np.amin(widthwise_lines[:,[1,3]], axis = 1) >= y_min - height_error) & (np.amin(widthwise_lines[:,[1,3]], axis = 1) <= y_min + height_error) & (np.amin(widthwise_lines[:,[0,2]], axis = 1) >= x_min - width_error) & (np.amax(widthwise_lines[:,[0,2]], axis = 1) <= x_max + width_error))[0]]
top_lines = widthwise_lines[np.where((np.amax(widthwise_lines[:,[1,3]], axis = 1) >= y_max - height_error) & (np.amax(widthwise_lines[:,[1,3]], axis = 1) <= y_max + height_error) & (np.amin(widthwise_lines[:,[0,2]], axis = 1) >= x_min - width_error) & (np.amax(widthwise_lines[:,[0,2]], axis = 1) <= x_max + width_error))[0]]

# if no lines found for any border, stop
if top_lines.size == 0 or bottom_lines.size == 0 or l_left.size == 0 or l_right.size == 0: print('No Lengthwise lines!')

# take median of left outer lengthwise lines
l_left_b = np.median(l_left[:,7])
l_left_m = np.median(l_left[:,4])

# take median of right outer lengthwise lines
l_right_b = np.median(l_right[:,7])
l_right_m = np.median(l_right[:,4])

# take median of top widthwise lines
top_lines_b = np.median(top_lines[:,6])
top_lines_m = np.median(top_lines[:,4])

# take median of bottom widthwise lines
bottom_lines_b = np.median(bottom_lines[:,6])
bottom_lines_m = np.median(bottom_lines[:,4])

# find interesction of lines
int_pt1 = line_intersect(l_left_m, l_left_b, bottom_lines_m, bottom_lines_b)
int_pt2 = line_intersect(l_right_m, l_right_b, bottom_lines_m, bottom_lines_b)
int_pt3 = line_intersect(l_left_m, l_left_b, top_lines_m, top_lines_b)
int_pt4 = line_intersect(l_right_m, l_right_b, top_lines_m, top_lines_b)

# draw intersections
cv2.circle(img, int_pt1, 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, int_pt3, 3, (255, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, int_pt2, 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, int_pt4, 3, (255, 255, 0), -1)

# show image
cv2.imshow('frame diff ', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original image:

[image]

Comment: if you know that it's a straight line then why cant you just assume that you can connect the last coordinate of side1 to the last coordinate of side 2?

Comment: In most cases, that has worked (it's how I initially did it, with some clustering to be a little rigorous). However, the ends of the lengthwise lines are not always so clear. They are obfuscated at times, and shadows/colors sometimes make it so the end is closer or further than it should be.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for your quadrilateral fit? Or at least post some intermediate results. You must end up with a binary mask of the court - can you show this?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644977/recognizing-corners-page-with-opencv-partialy-fails/67645614#67645614 Depending on your court mask, you could get a nice poly approximation using the convex hull + corner detection.

Comment: Try LineSegmentDetector

Comment: I'm going to work on this question today. I'll add the current code for the four line fit.

Comment: Added example. You can see Hough method has difficulty with the far lines.

Comment: Do you mind posting the original image, before the lines were drawn on?

Comment: Will do. I've since improved the lines by taking the median values at specific locations vs median slopes and intercepts, but it doesn't really concern with my question so I'll hold off on that part for now.

Comment: Added the original image. ALSO, I'm considering taking the closest service line (the horizontal line in the middle of the front court) instead of the back line. Knowing the true court dimensions, I can warp from those 4 points.

Comment: I tried an approach which detects the tennis court by comparing every pixel and seeing how blue it is. Then I use a Gaussian filter to get it to merge nearby blue areas, followed by Otsu thresholding, followed by finding a convex hull for those points, followed by simplifying that hull. I sort of got it to work, but I couldn't get the exact corners. It's a little off, because of the polygon simplification. Here's my best attempt: https://gist.github.com/nickodell/d45a50de665cbb38c80a3b0acadbd3d1

Comment: Thanks Nick! I learned some concepts from your example which will definitely help me throughout my project (I'm aiming for a full tennis tracking program). I'm going to post a solution I came up with this morning.